# Discord js - How to keep reacting to a message and editing the embed till a given time period

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js, embed

So I'm creating a bot which returns the urban dictionary meaning of the word. And on clicking the right arrow, it displays the next meaning.
But I'm able to do so only once.
What changes do I make so that I can react to the message and it would change the meaning till 10s after the command is given.
Because once I do the right arrow click, it shows me the next meaning, but I can't go back to the previous meaning or take the next meaning after we have reacted once.

```
async execute(message, args) {
        // if (!message.channel.nsfw) return message.channel.send("You can only send messages in a NSFW marked channel.")
        let worder = args[0];
        if (!worder) return message.channel.send("Specify a word")
        let defin = await ud.all(args.join(' ')).catch(e => {
            message.channel.send("Word not found")
            return;
        });


        message.channel.send({ embed: generateEmbed(defin, 0) }).then(async message => {
            if (defin.length < 1) return
            await message.react("➡️")
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
            };

            message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 1000 }).then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                let currentIndex = 0
                message.reactions.removeAll().then(async() => {
                    reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' ? currentIndex -= 1 : currentIndex += 1
                    console.log(currentIndex)
                    message.edit(generateEmbed(defin, currentIndex))

                    if (currentIndex !== 0) await message.react('⬅️')
                    console.log(currentIndex, defin.length)
                    if (currentIndex + 1 < defin.length) await message.react('➡️')
                })

            });

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So when using `awaitReactions` it only does this once, which is why it only works once. What you could do is instead use [messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd).

So instead you could have an array of all the message's ID you want to check for reactions, then in the messageReactionAdd you check if the id's match and if so, you have a new reaction!

```js
let listOfMessages = ["sampleId","000000000"]
client.messageReactionAdd = function(reaction,user){
    if(user.bot)return;
    if(listOfMessages.includes(reaction.message.id)){
        if(['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)){
            //do yer stuff
            //reaction.message.edit()
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What if there are a lot of users on the server? That would be difficult then haha

Answer (score 0):

Another method is just to refresh the awaitReactions by using a function.

```js
function checkForReactions(message){
   const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
   };
   message.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 1000 }).then(collected => {
      const reaction = collected.first();
      let currentIndex = 0
      message.reactions.removeAll().then(async() => {
         reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' ? currentIndex -= 1 : currentIndex += 1
         console.log(currentIndex)
         message.edit(generateEmbed(defin, currentIndex))
         if (currentIndex !== 0) await message.react('⬅️')
         console.log(currentIndex, defin.length)
         if (currentIndex + 1 < defin.length) await message.react('➡️');
        
         //Repeat the process!
         checkForReactions(message);
     });
   });
}
async execute(message, args) {
        // if (!message.channel.nsfw) return message.channel.send("You can only send messages in a NSFW marked channel.")
        let worder = args[0];
        if (!worder) return message.channel.send("Specify a word")
        let defin = await ud.all(args.join(' ')).catch(e => {
            message.channel.send("Word not found")
            return;
        });


        message.channel.send({ embed: generateEmbed(defin, 0) }).then(async message => {
            if (defin.length < 1) return
            await message.react("➡️")
            checkForReactions(message);
        });
    }
```